# A Dialog Controller

Tags: javascript, class, dialog

I have a dialog in my html with `id="divMyDialog1"`. This is associated with a javascript class with a name `MyDialog1`. (These names are just for illustration only.)

```
 MyDialog1 = function(divStr){
    this.divStr = divStr;
    ...
 }
```

I have loads of these dialogs and associated classes. What I would like to do is set up all these different string `id`s and associate them with their dialog class. Some Dialog Classes would have multiple instances but with different `divStr`.

**But how would this be done?**

I want something on the lines:

```
 let dialogARR = [];
 [{divStr: "divMyDialog1", className: MyDialog1},
 {divStr: "divSomethingElse", className: DialogWibble},
 {divStr: "divPingPong", className: DialogWobble}].forEach(o => dialogARR.push(new o.className(o.divStr)));
```

Comment: why not directly dialogARR= [MyDialog1('divMyDialog1'), ...] ?

Comment: I just thought there would be a better way. I thought I would be repeating the `new` each time. I would be repeating the same action, so instead just write a function to do it. But you are ommitting the `new`. **Why is that?** Even so. for interest, how would you set up the `forEach` so you could put the class name in the object and then do a `new` with it?

Comment: sorry, forgot `new`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop through the array, extracting the properties from each object and then calling the class constructor function with `new`.

```
dialogArr.forEach(({divStr, className}) => new className(divStr));
```

If you need the instances, you can use `.map()` instead of `.forEach()`, and it will return an array of the instances.

Answer (score 1):

You could just have:

```
class Dialog(){
   Constructor(name, class){
       this.name = name;
       this.class = class;
   }
}
```

And then initialize dialogs like this into the array:

```
let dialogARR = [];

 [new Dialog("divMyDialog1", "MyDialog1"), new Dialog("divMyDialog2", "MyDialog2")].forEach(o => dialogARR.push(o));
```

That's how I would go about it, please correct me if I'm wrong.